# gnu watch: justify on the lower left of the terminal

Tags: bash, watch

I want to apply a watch command on a mysql query every N seconds, but would like to have the results on the bottom left of the terminal instead of the top left:

```
watch -n 120 "mysql_query" | column -t"
```

Shows my results like so:

```
--------------------------
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
|                        |
|                        |
--------------------------
```

Whereas I would like them to have like so:

```
--------------------------
|                        |
|                        |
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
|xxxxxxxxxxx             |
--------------------------
```

Suggestion?

Comment: there's nothing in the man page for the standard watch command to indicate this is possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a straight-forward way to do this, but I managed to force it to work using the following approach. I haven't fully tested this so I cannot guarantee that this will work in all situations.

Using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TERM_HEIGHT=`tput lines`  # determine terminal height
WATCH_BANNER_HEIGHT=2  # account for the lines taken up by the header of "watch"
let VIS_LINES="TERM_HEIGHT - WATCH_BANNER_HEIGHT"  # height of visible area
(yes " " | head -n $VIS_LINES; cat | head -n $VIS_LINES) | tail -n $VIS_LINES
```

Post process the output of your command as it is called by `watch` e.g. (assuming the script was saved as `align_bottom`, made executable, and store somewhere within your `$PATH`):

```
watch -n 120 "mysql_query | column -t | align_bottom"
```

What the script does:

1. Determine the height (number of lines) of the terminal
2. Calculate the visible area of the `watch` output
3. Print blank lines to pad the output (pushing the output down)
4. Read in output from stdin, and trim it so we only show the top of the output if it extends beyond the screen. If you want to see the bottom of the output instead, simple remove the `head` command after `cat`.
5. `tail` the output of steps (3) and (4) so excess padding is removed and the final output fits snugly within `watch`

I have to admit this seems a little hackish, but hopefully it gets you closer to what you're trying to achieve.

---

#### Update:

It should also be possible to implement that as a function instead just so it can sit comfortably in `.bashrc`.

```
function align_bottom() {
  (( VIS = $(tput lines) - 2 ))  # height of visible area
  (yes " " | head -n $VIS; cat | head -n $VIS) | tail -n $VIS
}
typeset -fx align_bottom  # !! make it callable from subshell
```

Usage would be the same:

```
watch -n 120 "mysql_query | column -t | align_bottom"
```

Note that `watch` runs the given command using `sh -c`, therefore, as Dennis pointed out in the comments, on systems that does not link `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` the function approach shown above will not work.

It is possible to make it work usign:

```
watch -n 120 "mysql_query | column -t | bash -c align_bottom"
```

but for portability and usability, it's cleaner to simply use the shell script approach.

Comment: In your function version, you have a mismatched variable `$VIS_LINES` should be `$VIS`. The (exported) function works for me when `sh` is a symlink to Bash (CentOS), but not when it's a symlink to `dash` (Ubuntu).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks for pointing that out. I'll look into that when I get a chance.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Any suggestions? I don't have access to a machine with `dash` a.t.m, and the only thing I can come up with without having a system to try on is forcing bash on it (`...| bash -c align_bottom`).

Comment: `let` is a bashism, you can change it to `expr` or a simple `awk` script. The rest seems to be POSIX compatible.

Comment: @tripleee: You can avoid using an external utility and stay POSIX compliant by doing this: `VIS=$(($(tput lines) - 2))`. By the way, there's nothing wrong with using "bashisms" in a Bash script when portability to other shells is not a concern. The question is tagged `[bash]` after all. Another way to write the expression in Bash is: `(( VIS = $(tput lines) - 2 ))`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: I was responding to the complaint that this wasn't working in an environment where Bash was not the default shell. Fortunately it was not hard to fix, and as per your comment, it's even easier than I thought (although my suggestions might come in handy if your Bourne shell is pre-POSIX stoneage). Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee: The problem is that the function version doesn't work with a non-Bash `sh` when it doesn't import functions exported by the parent (or possibly support exporting functions either). In the script version, the shebang calls bash, so bashisms aren't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `watch` can do that, but what I'd do is use another tool to have multiple terminals and resize the one in which `watch` is running according to my needs.

A couple of these tools that can be useful are:

- [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)
- [byobu](http://byobu.co) (screen with some enhancements)
- [terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am already using gnu screen, but in this case I would like to be able to move the print out to the bottom left within the window itself, not with respect to gnu screen.

Comment: @avilella I don't think a process running under `screen` has any way to access the terminal under which `screen` is running.  Does your screen not take up the entire termina window?